# python перевод массы в кратные и дольные единицы

Tags: python

нужно написать программу перевода введенной массы в граммы, килограммы, тонны. Приставки, которые будет использовать программа: g – граммы, kg – килограммы, t – тонны.

Пример ввода:

```
12kg
```

Вывод:

```
12000g
0.012t
```

вот как получилось у меня, но это не правильно. как сделать так чтобы в вводимых данных с клавиатуры отделить число от граммов и т.д.?

```py
a = input()

if "kg" in a:
print(a/1000 + "t")
print(a*1000 + "g")

elif "g" in a:
print(a/1000 + "kg")
print(a/00000 + "t")

elif "t" in a:
print(a*1000 + "kg")
print(a/1000000 + "g")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию `input()` возвращает строковый тип `str`.

Поэтому, даже если вы введете число, вы все равно не сможете проводить с ним математические операции, так как переменная будет являться текстом.

---

**Допустим, мы вводим `12`**

Переменная `a` будет иметь тип `str` и содержать значение `'12'`

Чтобы привести его к числовому типу `int` достаточно применить к `input()` встроенную функцию `int()`

```
a = int(input())
```

Теперь `a` имеет тип `int` и значение `12`

---

Однако вы вводите также единицы измерения, так что строку `'12kg'`, содержащую буквы привести к числу не получится.

Для отделения `'kg'` можно воспользоваться стандартным методом `replace()`, который первым аргументом принимает строку, **которую нужно заменить**, а вторым - строку, **на которую нужно заменить**.

```
'12kg'.replace('kg', '')
```

Даная строка примет значение `'12'`, которое уже можно привести к числу и выполнять операции.

---

**Решение:**

```
a = input()

value = int(a.replace('kg', '').replace('g', '').replace('t', ''))

if "kg" in a:
    print(str(value / 1000) + "t")
    print(str(value * 1000) + "g")

elif "g" in a:
    print(str(value / 1000) + "kg")
    print(str(value / 100000) + "t")

elif "t" in a:
    print(str(value * 1000) + "kg")
    print(str(value / 1000000) + "g")
```

Comment: братик просто спас) и обьяснил четко ! от души тебе ! спасибо... только не понятно за value я такое еще не проходил..или что угодно можно написать?

Comment: value - это просто название переменной, в которой хранится отдельно число без kg, g и t. Можно назвать как угодно, но value - это значение по английский, поэтому так

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re
weights = {
    't': 1e-6,
    'kg': 1e-3,
    'g': 1
}
if match := re.search(r'([\d.]+)\s*?(t|k?g)', input()):
    value, unit = match.groups()
    
    grams = float(value) / weights.pop(unit)
    for u, v in weights.items():
        print(f'{grams * v}{u}')
```